# A problem is given to three students A, B and C whose chances of solving it are $1/2$, $3/4$ and $1/4$ respectively.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> A problem is given to three students A, B and C whose chances of solving it are $1/2$, $3/4$ and $1/4$ respectively. If the problem is solved, find the chance that only A has solved it.

Comment: Is there an independence assumption here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The problem is solved with probability
$$p(S)=1- \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{3}{4}\right)\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right).$$
Now recall the definition of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event) $P(A|S)$ where $A$ is the event that only student $A$ solved it.